# Is it possible to code in Firebug and save to remote directory?

Tags: firebug

This would save enormous amounts of time, as Firebug is what I use to debug anyways.

I would just like to save the changes I've made to a remote or even local directory. Is this possible?

(bonus: can I do php development also, and not just html/javascript/css?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the changes you made in Firebug for CSS and HTML by just copying it and pasting in your editor of choice. However inside Firebug itself there is no function for saving the contents that I am aware of.

I second the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/web-developer/) extension. It is amazing tool for writing CSS and HTML, as you can see the changes you make for CSS and HTML right in front of your eyes. Web Developer is almost an editor on its own built into the browser.

For PHP debugging with Firebug check out the [FirePHP](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firephp/) extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can view the rendered source using something like the Web Devloper toolbar (ie after your edits) and save that ***BUT***:

- No code formatting
- Only static HTML
- You can't view rendered CSS (in a way that makes it possible to save without stripping loads of junk)

So not entirely useful.

PHP is server-side. The browser (and thus Firebug) don't get to see it so it's a outright no to your second question.

On the side: if you find Firebug *that* much simpler for wholesale editing, you're doing something wrong. Your editor is pants or you need another screen for more desktop space. Have a go at trying something new to spruce up your workflow.

Answer (score 2):

You should try http://cssupdater.com  , cssUpdater syncs your FireBug css changes back to your original css files.

So you work in FireBug, hit the "Sync now" button in FireBug and reload the page!

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no automatic way to do that.

In addition, this would only work for plain HTML, JS and CSS files. If there anything *generated* on server side, you'll need to update your server-side templates by hand anyway, because the client (Firefox with Firebug) won't know about the template. It only seed the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427) to save edited pages, which, however, only works most of the time. It saves all files locally based on the current DOM.